# Getting JSON Object without Key

Tags: android, json

It is possible to retrieve a JSON object without a key name?

One more problem is that it is deep in the hierarchy. Please see this: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?apikey=2d0af97a020cd072d49059aa0bf13207&hash=ef7184ddbb03ed2f71da0efec112cf41&ts=1495035369

That is an intensively long JSON and has multiple objects.

I am trying to access this part of the JSON: {
        "id": 1010699,
        "name": "Aaron Stack", ..

I am using the following code:

```
private void parseResult(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
                String title = post.optString("results");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But I can't access it.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "I can't access it" means.

Comment: I want to get the name, id, and the description @CommonsWare

Comment: Isn't that object is accessible as `posts.results[3]`?

Comment: "I want to get the name, id, and the description" -- so... what is stopping you?

Comment: @JaysonTamayo i think you are confused between JsonObjects and JsonArray, You will get the name for JsonArray as key. use that to create 
 a JsonArray object and access data objects is a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON for this

```
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

and create POJO class for the corroesponding json result using [this](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com) link, Just paste your json data and create classes.

For eg your main pojo class name be *JsonResponseHolder*
And in your java code

```
  try {
        JsonResponseHolder jrh = new Gson().fromJson(responseString, 
                                            JsonResponseHolder.class);
        List<Results> results = jrh.getData().getResults(); 
         /// this will give the result objects                                                  
         /// and be sure to convert [] arrays to list for better data handling
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope this will help